# File locked for editing

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am doing some code that writes an Excel file. However, when opening the file created at the end of the `main` function, Open Office displays an error message that the file is locked by an unknown user. I checked and it seems I am closing all the references to the file and the workbook using the file.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Code**

```
public class StandingsFile
{
    private Workbook workbook;

    public StandingsFile(InputStream inputStream, File outputFile)
    {
        this.outputFile = outputFile;
        workbook = POIExcelFileProcessor.createWorkbook(inputStream);
    }

    public void write()
    {
        // Code where the sheets in the Excel file are modified

        POIExcelFileProcessor.writeWorkbook(workbook, outputFile);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        standingsExcelFile = new StandingsFile(StandingsCreationHelper.class.getResourceAsStream(TEMPLATE_FILENAME), outputFile);
        standingsExcelFile.write();

        try
        {
            Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
            dt.open(outputFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class POIExcelFileProcessor
{

    public static Workbook createWorkbook(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        Workbook workbook = null;

        try
        {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return workbook;
    }

    public static void writeWorkbook(Workbook workbook, File outputFile)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            workbook.write(fileOut);

            fileOut.flush();
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you close the output stream?

Comment: Added fileOut.close(); and it seems to work now :).

Comment: I did not know it would lock the file. You can add it as an answer :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remember to close the file when you're done with it, either explicitly with the `close` method (in a `finally` block) or with a try-with-resources statement.

This goes as a general rule, not just for using POI.